# Eclipse not recognizing my android phone - says target unknown

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am using the ADT eclipse for android development. I connected my phone then ran eclipse. Then when I run my android project, I get the window asking how you want to run it. I can see my phone listed there, but its not recognizing its target version.

As a result I am unable to run it on my phone. This is happening sometimes before, and now more often than usual.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: try reinstalling the usb driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's a weird one but you know how phones have "media" and "camera" mode and such, change that to "media" if I recall correctly, or "camera", it's something along those line! It was my old phone sorry, but this solved it!

Alec

Comment: I got it to work now. I tried restarting the phone, restarting my laptop, changed the camera mode from screen facing (2mp) to back facing (8mp), and now it recognized the phone version.

Comment: I wouldn't call it insight, my old HTC Desire HD, with JellyTime rom would show up as ?????? I found a post somewhere that said it was to do with the SD cards mount mode, I just parroted it on, I appreciate you accepting it as the right answer though, thanks, I wish I could tell you why it worked though.

Answer (score 0):

Its the camera made that works. I tried it for google nexus 4 and turning it to camera mode worked for me.
Here is the path where you can find the setting for nexus mobiles:
Settings > Device > Storage > Menu > USB computer connection

Answer (score 0):

For others still experiencing trouble having checked the connection mode, try these proposed solutions in the stated order till you get it working:

1. Check whether USB debugging is enabled. Try disabling it and enabling it again. Can't find this option? *Settings > Developer options > USB debugging*. Can't find Developer options? *Settings > About (phone) > Tap 7 times on Build Number*
2. Try a different cable (some users have experienced being able to charge, but not transfer data or charge and transfer data, but not get recognized by ADT)
3. Reboot phone
4. Reboot computer
5. Check your USB driver, especially if you're running Windows or Linux. On Windows, install Google USB driver from sdk-manager, then: *Device Manager > Find and right-click phone (usually under 'Portable devices') > Update driver software > Browse my computer for driver software > adt-folder-location/sdk/extras/google/usb-driver*. For further info, read up on http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up. (The "Setting up a Device for Development"-part)
6. Download and use a separate ADT
7. Try using [Android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)
8. Try finding and using an older ADT
9. Try using a different computer
10. Wait for next ADT update and quietly weep...