# Eclipse doesn't recognize Android device but adb does

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm using the ADT bundled version of Eclipse and using PhoneGap to develop the app. `adb devices` recognizes my device and I am able to debug the app onto my phone using the command line with PhoneGap (`phonegap run android --device`) as well as onto the emulator.

Eclipse is able to run it onto the emulator but doesn't recognize my device.

Drivers are installed.  Using Windows 8. ADT version of Eclipse. Device is an LG-P509 running Android 2.2. USB debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autogenerated minsdv version was 10 and my device is 8. Changing this down to 8 fixed it right away...

Comment: what is minsdv?!! you mean minsdk ?!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird one but see my answer here:

[Eclipse not recognizing my android phone - says target unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455526/eclipse-not-recognizing-my-android-phone-says-target-unknown/18455547#18455547)

I know, I discovered it by fluke, change how the memory stick mounts and somehow it works. I hope this helps, adb used to see my desire HD, but it was Android 2.3 eclipse wouldn't until I fiddled with the memory stick mount settings. If this doesn't help tell me via comments and I'll ask for more info and such but this weird fix often works for me.

Comment: i unmounted and remounted the SD card and restarted the phone but didn't work. Not sure what u mean in the linked answer about media vs. camera mode but my device only has a rear camera not a front. Also the linked question shows a device that partially appears in Eclipse whereas mine doesn't appear at all.

Comment: @Xenocideae is the eclipse  Android SDK directory the same as the one you are running ADB from?

Comment: yes, i verified by running `adb.exe devices` from the same directory that eclipse is getting the sdk and this command does show my device. Eclipse still doesn't see it.

Comment: @Xenocideae http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103383/android-avd-not-recognizing-device-but-adb-does does that work?

Comment: nope, I already had that marked to ask every time. When I click "Run" in Eclipse it shows me the emulator that I have running but doesn't show my phone...

Comment: @Xenocideae what about other projects in Eclipse? Restart Eclipse? I don't know sorry but I feel bad just leaving you, do you have any more information at all?

Comment: just saw the minsdk version (see answer). Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: @Xenocideae have some upvotes because it's a good question, I'm sure it'll hit me one day, I didn't know it'd hide non-applicable versions for me :) Remember to tick your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with LG P700 and at beginning eclipse also dont recognize my phone.
I searched for a driver and installed it. This was solving my problem.

Maybe you should also install the drivers again.

http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGP509

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, finally solved it.
What did the trick was lowering both "minSdkVersion" and "targetSdkVersion" for
my app. Apparently they were both too high at first for my device.
Set them both as low as possible and see if that changes something.